# Why is this "Only" used here?

Tags: adverbs, lists

Man is now **only** more active - not more happy - nor more wise, than he was 6000 years ago.
BY POE

Why is this "Only" used here? What is it trying to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three qualities mentioned in the statement, "more active", "more happy" and "more wise". Of those,

> Man is **now** (at this time) **only** (just) more active - (and not the other two).

Its just singling out "more active" as the only quality of the three that can be attributed to man.